# Do you need a BIM360 license to acces BIM360 files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

For a school project I need to display a BIM360 model in the forge viewer. I can't find clear information on whether or not I need to have a BIM360 license to do that. Can I use the API to get the model without my own BIM360 account? (My mentor has the BIM-model in his account)

Also I read that the forge viewer uses the data-derivative API to convert to a it's own format, this uses 0.2 credits every time. Can's I just convert the model once and then store it somewhere?

Thanks,
DrawMen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to be able to see and access the model in BIM 360, the owner will have to share it with you.
This forum post seems to indicate that you would indeed need a BIM360 license.
[https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-support/do-people-need-a-bim-360-design-license-to-use-docs-online/td-p/9573036#:~:text=Anyone%20who%20needs%20to%20review,license%20is%20not%20a%20BYOS](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-support/do-people-need-a-bim-360-design-license-to-use-docs-online/td-p/9573036#:%7E:text=Anyone%20who%20needs%20to%20review,license%20is%20not%20a%20BYOS)

There is a way to share files with publc links, but I don't think this will give you access to a forge viewer. (only the file)

https://bim360basics.com/2020/04/22/public-links-share-bim-360-files-with-anyone/

That being said, depending on the type of file you are trying to view.  A lot of Autodesk product now have a feature called "shared view" which let you create a 3ds view for the forge viewer that can be shared with anyone with a URL.  It might be worth asking your mentor if he would be willing to create a shared view for you to use.

Comment: Thx for the answer, it indeed seems that I need a license to acces the file with the Forge API. Do you by any chance now where the files that are converted are stored? Are they put in temporary storage on the autodesk side? I'm just wondering if I can convert the model I need once and then use it for the viewer.

Comment: I don't know where the file are kept.  I don't think you can download the viewer SVF files unless you used to the model derivative API to generate them in the first place.  That being said, these files has to be downloaded to be displayed by the client, you might be able to grab the different files you need from what is downloaded by your browser when viewing the 3d preview.  However, since there is no publicly available documentation of the SVF format, it might be complicated to figure out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look into if I can download the files that way.